# SQL Server - Update rows based on a list

Tags: sql, vb.net, list, sql-update

I'm working with Windows Forms - VB.NET.

Here's what I have:

- A `ListView` with checkboxes set to `True`
- A `Button` (triggers the update)
- A database table with similar fields as the `ListView`

What I want to happen:

- when the user clicks the `Button`, all items on the `ListView` with checkbox checked will be updated.

My progress:

- I've already collected the `ID` of the checked items and stored them in an array. I'll be using this to update the database table.

The problem:

- I don't know how to put them in the `SqlCommand.Parameters`
- Also, I don't know the update command for such scenario (where in/exist (@parameters))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, you can use [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). These let you continue to deal with the separate IDs on separate rows, perform SQL joins, etc. There are plenty of examples on the page I've linked to, e.g.:

```vb
Using connection
  ' Create a DataTable with the modified rows.
  Dim addedCategories As DataTable = _
    CategoriesDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)

  ' Define the INSERT-SELECT statement.
  Dim sqlInsert As String = _
  "INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)" _
  & " SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName" _
  & " FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc;"

  ' Configure the command and parameter.
  Dim insertCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection)
  Dim tvpParam As SqlParameter = _
     insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( _
    "@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories)
  tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
  tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType"

  ' Execute the query
  insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

You could easily replace that `INSERT` with an `UPDATE`, as shown earlier on the page:

```
UPDATE dbo.Categories
SET Categories.CategoryName = ec.CategoryName
FROM dbo.Categories INNER JOIN @tvpEditedCategories AS ec
ON dbo.Categories.CategoryID = ec.CategoryID;
```

And adjust parameter names accordingly.

Comment: Aha, I haven't used ADO.NET with the latest versions of SQL Server, sounds great

Comment: @domanokz - there are a series of suggestions at the top of the article about how to do this in previous versions. Best suggestion (if it's an "unlimited" number of IDs to pass) would probably to put them in XML and pass that across.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use a single call to the database, for that you would need to build a string with the command, I don't think you can pass a list as parameter to a command / sp.

The update command:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [field1] = value1, [field2] = value2
WHERE [ID] IN (id1, id2, ..., idN)
```

Comment: Is that it? WHERE IN() ? Ah, another question, how am I gonna pass the id's thru SqlCommand.SqlParameter?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a list through SqlParameter, if you want to use a single command, you'll have to build your string with that WHERE IN and the list you got.